# Syntax highlight for scheme

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I just modified an answer and I can see that there are some missing highlights for the scheme language.

It's unclear what is not handled by the highlighter. But I'd say that the current functions are quite "standard" enough to get added to highlighting.

- begin
- display
- newline
- set!

Comment: This question I assume? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745293/read-input-from-console-to-a-list-in-scheme

Comment: Yes, that question but if SO uses Google prettify that's different.

Comment: Just checked the supported languages, and lisp and scheme are put in the same bag with a really small subset of standard functions.